# Lua - Get instance of caller when using arguments using a (objective-)c bridge

Tags: objective-c, c, lua

I am trying to create a simple bridge between lua and my 'native' code. Using the following code I am adding an LuaObject class so that it can used from the lua code.

```
-(instancetype) init
{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {
        // temp for testing script
        L = luaL_newstate();
        luaL_openlibs(L);

        [self registerClazz:[LuaObject class]];
        [self pushFunction:getObjectWithName name:@"getObjectWithName"];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) pushFunction:(lua_CFunction)function name:(NSString*)name
{
    lua_pushcfunction(L, function);
    lua_setglobal(L, [name cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
}

int getObjectWithName(lua_State *luaState)
{
    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:lua_tostring(luaState, 1)];
    lua_pop(luaState, 1);

    LuaObject *luaObject = [objectMap objectForKey:name]

    void *luaUserdataPtr = lua_newuserdata(luaState, sizeof(LuaObject*));
    void *luaObjectPtr = (__bridge_retained void *)luaObjectPtr;
    memcpy(ptr, &luaObjectPtr, sizeof(LuaObject*));

    luaL_getmetatable(luaState, "LuaObject");
    lua_setmetatable(luaState, -2);

    return 1;
}

-(void) registerClazz:(Class)clazz
{
    luaL_Reg methods[] = {
        { "talk", &proxyLuaObjectCall },
        { "say", &proxyLuaObjectCall },
        { NULL, NULL }
    };

    luaL_newmetatable(L, "LuaObject");
    luaL_newlib(L, methods);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
}

int proxyLuaObjectCall(lua_State *luaState, void* caller)
{
    luaL_checkudata(luaState, 0, "LuaObject");
}
```

Now when `proxyLuaObjectCall` is called from lua, I want to be able to retrieve the instance of the LuaObject on which the method is being called. Above code works perfectly when calling a method without any arguments. But when calling a method that has any arguments the code fails with the error

> bad argument #0 to '' (LuaObject expected, got table).

For example when using the following code in lua:

**This works perfectly:**

```
myObject = getObjectWithName("nominator");
myObject.talk();
```

**This fails miserably**

```
myObject = getObjectWithName("nominator");
myObject.say("And the winner is");

// Result: bad argument #0 to 'say' (LuaObject expected, got table).
```

--

```
myObject = getObjectWithName("nominator");
myObject.say("And the winner is", "Joan");

// Result: bad argument #0 to 'say' (LuaObject expected, got string).
```

I have tried changing the index when calling a method that has arguments but nothing on the stack contains a reference to the LuaObject instance.

What am I doing wrong here? What should I do to retrieve the instance of the LuaObject on which the method is called?

Comment: `0` (in the `luaL_checkudata` call) is not a valid stack index. You can catch such errors by compiling Lua with API checks enabled (`LUA_USE_APICHECK` preprocessor macro).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything looks good to me, but you probably should be calling it using the method notation:

```
myObject = getObjectWithName("nominator");
myObject:say("And the winner is");
```

`myObject:say("")` is the same as `myObject.say(myObject, "")`, which is what your API seems to expect.

On the other hand, [@siffiejoe may be right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693427/lua-get-instance-of-caller-when-using-arguments-using-a-objective-c-bridge/24725750#comment38354423_24693427) as [according to this PiL example](http://www.lua.org/pil/28.2.html), it should probably be `luaL_checkudata(luaState, 1, "LuaObject")`. In fact, you may need both of these changes to make it work.

Comment: It worked :) I should have read some more about the lua syntax, it was stupid of me to assume easy object-oriented code.